# how could i make this function recursive and remove the for in loop here. where i get the result of Maark, Maary etc by using this function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

how could i make this function recursive and remove the for in loop here. 
where i get the result of Maark, Maary etc by using this function.

```
function get_suggestion_array_from_object () {
    var test_searchstring = 'Ma';
    var test_current_object_string = '{"a":{"r":{"k":0,"y":0}, "s":{"s":0,"y":0}}}';
    var test_current_object = JSON.parse(test_current_object_string);
    var suggestion_array = [];
    for (var item in test_current_object) {
        var one = item;
        for( var item2 in test_current_object[item]) {
            var two =  item2;
            console.log( test_searchstring + one + two );
            }
        }
    }
}

get_suggestion_array_from_object ()
```

Comment: use Array.prototype.forEach() on Object.key()

Answer (score 1):

```
function traverse(path, string = ""){
  const result = [];
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(path)){
    if(typeof value === "object"){
       result.push(...traverse(value, string + key));
    } else {
       result.push(string + key);
   }
 }
 return result;
}
```

So one can do:

```
 const result = traverse({a: { r: {k: 0, y: 0}}}, "M");
```

Comment: Jonas W can you do this for my code which i given. Thanks

Comment: should probably mention the whole infinite loop gotcha in these kind of iterators.

Comment: @imraihan i provided a working implementation for your problem. What else do you want??

Comment: @dandavis dont see an infinite loop here (except the path has circular references)

Comment: well, not from feeding it a literal, no, but in general, that kind of mechanism is fooled by self-refs...